# How can you get the Azure automation script for just a single service?

Tags: azure, automation, azure-resource-manager

How can you get the Azure automation script for just a single service?

In this case I've selected an App Service Plan, but when I click on it's "Automation script" in the Azure Portal, I get the script for everything *(minus the various resource types "that cannot be exported yet" )*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, export function only allows to export everything in the resource group, so you get an ARM template that represents the resource group.

If you want to get an ARM template solely for that resource, please deploy it into it's own resource group and then use the Automation script option.

Alternatively, you can use [armviz](http://armviz.io) to get a visual representation. When you click on a particular element, it will take you directly to that object in the arm template. Not exactly what you are looking for, but might give you enough.

Comment: huh? how does your first sentence explain why export is done in that manner? it doesn't. because arm templates and export are completely different things. Also, how do you use armviz to navigate resource groups?

Comment: Automation Script exports an ARM template, which is defined at the resource group level.  You can import that automation script into ARMVIZ to have a more visual view.

Answer (score 0):

You can't export just a single resource if there are multiple resources in the resource group, but maybe visual studio can help.

If you export the template and load it in VS as an arm template project, you can easily delete the other resources from the sidebar and leave just the one you need. You might also need to clean up the vars/params though.